# WooCommerce shows the placeholder image when using get_image()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, product

I am developing a custom WooCommerce theme and every time I try to retrieve a product's image, all I get is the placeholder image. I've already set the image in the back-end so it should work properly, but it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 2
);

$products = get_posts($args);

foreach($products as $the_product) {
    $wc_product = new WC_Product($the_product->id);
    echo $wc_product->get_image('shop_thumbnail');
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Could you help me out with this, please?

Comment: You can get the image URL using `$imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($the_product->ID));`. Does this return the URL you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the answer to my problem, I used "id" instead of "ID" when accessing the property of the WC_Product object.